# Kentico Related Pages from a different site

Tags: kentico

I have multiple sites (site1.abc.com, site2.abc.com) that share the same Kentico 9 instance/installation. With this I can re-use/share page template and other resources across sites easily. One problem is when I'm on site #1 and try to add Related Pages and select a page on site #2, the related content doesn't show. It looks like Related Pages only work for pages on the same site/domain. Is there a way to use Related content cross sites?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Related pages are specific to a page on a site.  In the background, the relationship is simply a left document id, a right document id and a relationship ID.  When the repeater for the relationship joins the content, it looks specifically for the document IDs on the current site.

You'd need to create your own rendition of the related documents web part and modify the `SetupControl()` method.  Maybe all you need is to simply remove the `.SiteName` property assignment, maybe you need to modify something else, I've not tried this before with related pages.